# Can you set a default value for an argument in a remote CFC function?

Tags: coldfusion, arguments, remote-access, cfc

The ColdFusion 8 documentation states the following about the "required" attribute of CFARGUMENT:

> "All arguments are required when invoked as a web service, irrespective of how they are defined."

However, I don't want ColdFusion to throw an exception when an argument is missing from the request. I want to handle it myself as part of the request. So, can I set a default value for the required argument?

Comment: Look like 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326873/coldfusion-web-service-issue/6327300#6327300

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes and no.**

Officially, you *cannot*, because the WSDL produced by ColdFusion leaves out an important requirement in the XML that is necessary to allow optional parameters to not be passed. This  attribute is "minOccurs". So, while it is perfectly valid for you to set the "default" attribute (along with a value)--you will never be able to set it to "required=false" and take advantage of the default value, because the remote method will always require something to be passed.

However, there there *is* a way to *unofficially* set an optional parameter, and set its default if needed:

1. Generate the WSDL to your CFC using the standard "?wsdl" parameter at the end, and save the code out into its own document.
2. Find the arguments you've defined that you want to be optional:

> ```
> <element name="test">
>       <complexType>
>         <sequence>
>           <element name="a" type="xsd:string"/>
>           <element name="b" type="xsd:string"/>
>           <element name="c" type="xsd:double"/>
>           <element name="d" type="xsd:boolean"/>
>         </sequence>
>       </complexType>
> </element>
> ```

and add the "minOccurs" attribute, setting it to 0:

```
<element name="test">
  <complexType>
    <sequence>
      <element name="a" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="b" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="c" type="xsd:double" minOccurs="0"/>
      <element name="d" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
</element>
```

3. Invoke your webservice like so, using the "omit" attribute for the arguments that you do not wish to pass:

> ```
> <cfinvoke webservice="http://localhost/mysavedwsdl.cfm" returnvariable="result" method="runTest">
>   <cfinvokeargument name="a" omit="no" value="test123" />   
>   <cfinvokeargument name="b" omit="no" value="test456" />
>   <cfinvokeargument name="c" omit="yes" />
>   <cfinvokeargument name="d" omit="yes" /> 
> </cfinvoke>
> ```

Source: [Issues when calling a ColdFusion web service with optional arguments.](http://www.jalpino.com/index.cfm/event/read/entry/Issues_when_calling_a_Coldfusion_web_services_with_optional_arguments)

Comment: Thank you. I have a pre-built WSDL, so I have added default="" to each argument.

Answer (score 1):

in CF9 CFScript:

```
component // {
    output='true'
 {

    remote function testMethod (
        string argument1='testValue'
    ) 
        output='true'
    {
        writeOutput(arguments.argument1);
    }
}
```

or tag version, should work in CF8:

```
<cffunction name="testMethod">
    <cfargument name="arg1" type="string" default="default">
</cffunction>
```

Comment: He is working on CF8, and the posted code for CF8 doesn't work. I know because that was my first answer, then I went back and tested it...and it failed miserably.

Comment: Odd, I just tried this on a CF8 server and it worked fine:

<cfcomponent output="true">
        <cffunction name="test" output="true" access="remote">
            <cfargument name="arg1" required="true" type="string" default="testValue">

            <cfoutput>#arg1#</cfoutput>
        </cffunction>
    </cfcomponent>

Comment: Ben, you have the argument set to 'required="true"', the OP is requesting info on whether or not you can have an optional parameter, which would be 'required="false"'. Try flipping it to false, setting a default parameter, and trying again. You should ultimately see an error about invalid arguments.

Comment: OP: "So, can I set a default value for the required argument?"  He has already stated he realizes that the parameters are required for remote functions.  His workaround is to set a default and simulate the optional argument from there.  All he is asking is how to set a default for an argument.

Comment: A default argument is 100% invalid if it is always supplied when calling the function--and without using the workaround specified above--the function call would always require the argument to be passed, thereby negating the default parameter. "Can you set a default value for an argument in a remote CFC function?"...Yes. "Will you be able to use it?"...No, not without the intervention above. It's important for us to paint the larger picture with our answers on the Stack.